# Doubt: "orocos+ros realtime?"

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello i'm trying to create an rc helicopter in a gazebo 9. I am using ros kinetic and orocos-toolchain 2.9 with rtt_ros_integration-2.9. Right now i'm leaving the xenomai part for real hardware.

My doubt is if i use ros along with orocos(xenomai patched) will it be as much hard real time as using orocos alone with xenomai patched orocos?

What i want is hard real time control of the dron movement. What i like about ros is the libraries and tools it provides for robot development like rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282980/doubt:-%22orocos+ros-realtime?%22/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see some previous questions about this. The situation has not changed much.

See #q191288 and especially #q206052, which links to a nr of other questions about ROS and real-time.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-17**:
You might also be interested in the presentation by @Jan Carstensen titled "RTROS – A real-time extension to the Robot Operating System" at ROSCon16 ([video](https://vimeo.com/187696090)). That talks about a real-time adaptation of ROS 1, but that has not been released.